# Why is $\partial_{\mu}x^{\nu} = \delta^{\nu}_{\mu}$?

Tags: tensor-calculus, notation, differentiation

In Blundell's book on QFT, one can find the following

[image]

Is this because of:

$$\partial_{\mu}x^{\nu} = \partial_{\mu}x^{\nu^{'}} \partial_{\nu^{'}}x^{\mu}$$

$$\partial_{\mu}x^{\nu} = \Lambda_{\mu}^{\nu^{'}} \Lambda_{\nu^{'}}^{\mu} = \delta^{\nu}_{\mu}$$

Or am I missing something here?

EDIT:

$$ \partial_{\mu}x^{\nu} = \frac{\partial x^{\nu}}{\partial x^{\mu}} = \frac{\partial x^{\nu}}{\partial x^{\mu^{'}}} \frac{\partial x^{\mu^{'}}}{\partial x^{\mu}} = \Lambda^{\nu}_{\mu^{'}} \Lambda_{\mu}^{\mu^{'}} = \delta^{\nu}_{\mu}  $$

Comment: $\partial_\mu$ means $\tfrac{\partial}{\partial x^\mu}$ by definition. It's just a shorthand notation. Or are you worried about the positioning of the indices?

Comment: This relations holds for a flat manifold (where your coordinates are independent of one another) For example Zee uses this equation (and also $\partial_{\mu}x_{\nu}$ to represent the Minkowski metric) while representing the Lie algebra of the Lorentz group in their differential operator form). Group theory in a nutshell  for physicists -Zee

Comment: Maybe it would help to expand in components. For instance, $\partial_2 x^3$ simply means $\partial z / \partial y$, which is simply zero.

Comment: As I understand it now, this relation is only true for independent coordinate systems and would not hold for something like the polar coordinates whos coordinates are clearly not independent ?

Comment: @256ABC What do you mean by polar coordinates being dependent on one another?  All (non-redundant) coordinates are independent.

Comment: I get it now.. They are independent. I misinterpreted the comment from @R.Rankin .. But it makes a lot of sense now . Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All you need to do is think through what the notation means.

Here is an example in rectangular coordinates $(t,x,y,z)$:
$$
\partial_0 x^0 = \frac{\partial}{\partial t} t = 1,
\; 
\partial_0 x^1 = \frac{\partial}{\partial t} x = 0,
\; 
\partial_0 x^2 = \frac{\partial}{\partial t} y = 0,
\; \partial_0 x^3 = \frac{\partial}{\partial t} z = 0,
$$
$$
\partial_1 x^0 = \frac{\partial}{\partial x} t = 0,
\; 
\partial_1 x^1 = \frac{\partial}{\partial x} x = 1,
\; 
\partial_1 x^2 = \frac{\partial}{\partial x} y = 0,
\; \partial_1 x^3 = \frac{\partial}{\partial x} z = 0,
$$
and so on. (You can fill in the rest).

After doing this, you can reflect that the very meaning of these partial derivative symbols is ``change of (thing) while the other coordinates are constant''. Therefore the result holds for any system of coordinates.